# Can the communication of RFID tag and RFID reader be simulated by tcp comunication?

Tags: tcp, rfid

Can the communication of RFID tag and RFID reader(EPC Gen2 standard)  be simulated by tcp comunication? 
What's the distinction between the two types of comunication

Comment: I don't really get your question.  What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I want to develop a RFID Simulation System ,But i am not sure that if i can simulate the communication process of RFID tag and RFID reader with tcp communication.

Comment: at which platform are you simulating it? `Matlab`?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code a `tcp client` simulating a *tag* and a `tcp server` simulating an *interrogator* then it could be accomplished. But you have to notice that the comunication protocol within RFID tags and Readers it's declared in ISO 18000-6C

regards!